# Process killed by kernel

Tags: 16.04, ffmpeg

I'm having my ffmpeg processes killed by the kernel when the system runs out of available memory.

I'd rather the process simply run slower, than get killed. My OSX machine seems to do accomplish this.

How could I do this on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is called "swapping". If you designate a disk partition or a specially created file as "swap space", Ubuntu will swap things out, and when the things are needed again, swap them in.

See `man mkswap`, `man swapon` and `man fstab`.

When setting up an Ubuntu systems, I usually set up a swap partition 2 or 3 times my RAM size. YMMV.